# how to change a database cell from aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to show a video and count how many views it gets. I have a cell in the database for the views, but I don't know how to update it every time I click in the video.

This is how I get the videos from the database into the aspx page:

```
string sql = "SELECT file,hero,username, views FROM VIDEOS";
DataTable dt = MyAdoHelper.ExecuteDataTable(fileName, sql);
int i = dt.Rows.Count;
for (int c = 0; c < i; c++)
{
    byte[] vid = (byte[])dt.Rows[c][0];
    string hero = (string)dt.Rows[c][1];
    string path3 = Server.MapPath("/potg") + "\\" + hero +c+ ".mp4";
    string name = Path.GetFileName(path3);      
    string username2 = (string)dt.Rows[c][2];
    int views = (int)dt.Rows[c][3];
    File.WriteAllBytes(path3, vid);
    span += "<li data-views ='"+views+"' data-name='" + name + "' onclick='potgShow(this)'><a href='#'>"+username2+" " + hero + " #"+c+" </a></li>";
}
```

How can I write the views back to the database?

Comment: You will need to probably write an update statement?  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: no. actualy i dont know how to do it. can u help me pls?

Comment: Does your VIDEOS table have a primary key?

Comment: @neildt yes. but the views's column and the videos's column are in the same table